# What is react-empty: *?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[react-empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSvaa.png)

```
<div data-reactroot>
<!-- react-empty: 3 -->
<!-- react-empty: 26 -->
</div>
```

What is this node ? Why can it render to a React Component ? How to do like this?

Answer (score 12):

This is actually part of [React's internal support for things like `null`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4b734f7a025c828be8c5d85f7c8d88679ae8f952/src/renderers/dom/shared/ReactDOMEmptyComponent.js#L39):

```
// A perfectly valid component
() => null

// Also a perfectly valid component
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    if (this.props.hidden) return null;
    return <p>My component implementation</p>;
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow! thank!  If I ajax to get a server-render Component string like '<div data-react-class="Show" data-react-props="{}"></div>', I want to mount it in this node. How to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with `React >= 16`, you won't see `<!-- react-empty: X -->` anymore

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part of `React` code which is create this:

```
var nodeValue = ' react-empty: ' + this._domID + ' ';
    if (transaction.useCreateElement) {
      var ownerDocument = hostContainerInfo._ownerDocument;
      var node = ownerDocument.createComment(nodeValue);
      ReactDOMComponentTree.precacheNode(this, node);
      return DOMLazyTree(node);
    } else {
      if (transaction.renderToStaticMarkup) {
        // Normally we'd insert a comment node, but since this is a situation
        // where React won't take over (static pages), we can simply return
        // nothing.
        return '';
      }
      return '<!--' + nodeValue + '-->';
    }
  },
```

So basically if your component return null, it will create a comment which showing this element is empty, but React take care of that for you by putting a comment there like `<!-- react-empty: 3 -->` all JavaScript frameworks try to get use of comment in the DOM, to show they handle the code, similar one is ng-if in angular for example...

Comment: I wish the English was more clear - I can almost understand this answer.